# Error while pushing a newly created react native app onto the Github or Gitlab

Tags: reactjs, git, react-native, github, gitlab

**Background :**

I have created a new react-native app using `react-native init`. Now I want to push this new repo to GitHub/GitLab with an initial commit message where I am facing the issue.

**Issue:**

While trying to push the project on the master branch of an empty repo I am getting a broken pipe error.

[image]

I am working on multiple projects and pushing the commits over ssh in different repositories on both Github and GitLab. There is no issue with old projects. Only when I create a new react-native app and try to push that in a new repo I am facing this issue. Can someone help me with this and tell me why this error is coming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was happened due to firewall software installed in the system. So if you are facing a similar kind of issue I am listing some of the things that might help:-

1. Check for any firewall software installed in the system.
2. Check for your internet connection.
3. Make sure your files don't exceed the git files limit if they do try to use git LFS.
4. If pushing via HTTP try increasing http.postbuffer size.